# YouTube thumbnail displayed as website preview (in LinkedIn)

Tags: html, preview

I made a basic front-end web page where I embedded a single video from YouTube inside an iframe element.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/link-to the-video" frameborder="0" id="mysong" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The problem arises when I link this page on LinkedIn. The video thumbnail becomes the preview for the page. It is kind of annoying as I don't want my website to be associated with the YouTube thumbnail, but rather want to use a different image as the preview.

Is there something I can add to my webpage to overwrite this behaviour and display a different preview? Here's what I mean by "preview":

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://link-to-image.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can not help you more than this as you do not have any code.
In the head of your website place this and set it to an image you want and it should work.

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://link.to/image.png" />
```

Comment: No, but this did `<meta property="og:image" content="http://link-to-picture.png"/>`

Comment: Thanks for your help, you were going in the right direction!